# How can I cbind() sets of data frames in a loop to generate multiple data sets

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I have let say 4 data sets  `f1,f2,i1,i2`.  I want to `cbind()` `f1` with `i1` and `f2` with `i2`.

I can use

```
v1<-cbind(f1,i1)
v2<-cbind(f2,i2)
```

but I want  to do this in some sort of loop.

I know the question is very basic. But after lots of searching I am still unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` to `cbind` the corresponding columns of both datasets

```
lst <- setNames(Map(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = "^f\\d+")),
        mget(ls(pattern = "^i\\d+"))), paste0("v", seq_along(f1)))
```

to create a `list` of datasets.

#### data

```
f1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
f2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = 11:20)
i1 <- data.frame(col3 = 11:15, col4 = 16:20)
i2 <- data.frame(col3 = 21:30, col4 = 31:40)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply akrun.  May be you can help me with other coding i have posted below.thanks

Comment: Hello. I am looking to do the same thing, but I don't understand this code. I already have a list of the data frames I want to merge (a and a_1, b and b_1, etc.), but how do I merge the data sets and assign them to a variable in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is more simplistic:

```
Map(cbind,list(f1,f2),list(i1,i2))
```

This code should work

Comment: v<-mapply(cbind, list(f1,f2),list(i1,i2), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

Comment: above code works the same as Onyambu.Thanks a lot members for answering.After generating a list of datasets called v. i have applied glm to the models

Comment: Now i want to cross validate.I have split the data into test and train.My problem is that i have list of models ,test and training data.i want to apply predict function.but i am getting error .here is my coding  .

Comment: v<-mapply(cbind, int, fac, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
sample = sample.split(v, SplitRatio = .75)
train = subset(v, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(v, sample == FALSE)
# Fitting Generalized Linear Models on data sets#
models<-lapply(train,function(x)glm(EverBF  ~    smokelesstobacco , family = binomial(link="logit"), data = x))                                        y.pred.im <-  lapply(predict(models, newdata = test))
  Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: Is you train and test data in numerical format? do you have your folds?? or you do not need them?

Comment: `Map(predict,models,test)` You have done a lot of `lapply` all this can be combined to one or two `mapply` statements..

Comment: my test and train data consists of both numeric and categorical data

Comment: by folds do you mean simulation?i will simulate the whole code  at the end.but now problem is when i use this code                                             
> p= mapply(function(s, l) predict(s, newdata=l), models, testing, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  i get a list in which same value is predicted for all the observations.that is very confusing.it will be nice if someone shares his or her experience to solve this problem thanks